# Javascript not getting executed with PhantomJS on Raspberry

Tags: php, parsing, phantomjs

i'm running a Raspberry with PHP & PhantomJS to get a few informations of a website.
This used to work flawlessly until this week (no changes were made).

When using PhantomJS, i'm just getting the source code like with file_get_contents("http://...") - where certain information is missing.

PHP side:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs site.js', $s);
$s = implode($s);
```

PhantomJS Script (site.js)

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.open("http://...", function() {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Someone got an idea? Maybe the site blocked access by headless browsers?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using PhantomJS 1.9.8 on my Raspberry.
I'm getting Unable to load resource (#87URL:)Error code: 301. Description: Protocol "" - also --ssl-protocol=any is set. I found 3 URLs in the source, which are having "no protocol", so start with //randomsite.com/abc

Comment: updated the first comment, it's 1.9.8

Comment: Seems like a redirect bug. You may try PhantomJS 2.1.1, but I don't know if there are available executables that you can trust. I've compiled version 2.0.1-dev on my RPi, but I really cannot recommend that. It takes ages (more than 8 hours). Have also tried to use the `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` commandline option?

Comment: okay, yes, i've tried that also. When i use both "phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true site.js" i get Error code: 202. Description: Error downloading / server replied: Forbidden.
Can't i just remove those resources? My PC browser is throwing a message that one site is using a weak SHA1 signature

Comment: Sure, you can `abort()` the download of those resources in a `page.onResourceRequested` callback, but that doesn't mean that the page will start to work. The JS that follows the problematic resources probably depends on it and will not run properly.